# Using Html entity in a label

Tags: html, label, zk, html-entities

How do I add an html entity within a label. I am using ZK Ajax Framework. For e.g.,

```
<hlayout hflex="1">
      <toolbarbutton label="More" /><html:b style="color: blue;">&amp;raquo;</html:b>
</hlayout>
```

I am adding a html element next to the toolbarbutton. Instead, I want to add it within the label of the toolbarbutton itself.

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by ZK out of the box: look at component reference for the "toolbarbutton" - it doesn't support any children.

Comment: "toolbarbutton" - it doesn't support any children. yes you are right but in above code it does not have any child. look again :)

Comment: @Aman The idea was that if you want to add something to toolbarbutton - like an ampersand with a quote - it's not supported out of the box. And, yes, I think I didn't get the markup right :)